# source path does not exist : resources\android\icon\drawble-hdpi-icon.png?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

ionic platform add android 
and 
ionic build android

```
 source path does not exist  :
 resources\android\icon\drawble-hdpi-icon.png
```

so any one know how fix this ?

Comment: It's `\drawable-`, not `\drawble-`.

Answer (score 1):

Save an icon.png file within the resources directory at the root of the Cordova project. The icon image’s minimum dimensions should be 192x192 px, and should have no rounded corners. Note that each platform will apply it’s own mask and effects to the icons. For example, iOS will automatically apply it’s custom rounded corners, so the source file should not already come with rounded corners. run below command that will generate icons for you.

`ionic resources --icon`

Or you can place drawble-hdpi-icon.png(72x72) file at resources/android/icon/ folder. you have to create file with name drawble-hdpi-icon.png and size (72x72)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i change the backslash (\) to slash (/) in config.xml under `<platform name="android">` in  `resources\android\icon\drawable-hdpi-icon.png` and it works for me ...

Answer (score 0):

The error can be fixed by running the command :

> ionic resources

Docs : https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/resources/